SearchKit columns to mailing tokens
Is it possible to use the results of a list created with SearchKit - for example, using column names as tokens - in CiviMail message templates?
My goal would be to be able to use the result columns of multiple connected contacts, relationships and pledges queried with SearchKit as a paste-in value in the "Email - send now (to 50 or less)" menu item under "Action" above the result list.
Thanks for any suggestions!
Pál

Have you seen https://civicrm.org/extensions/searchkit-tokens ?
Instructions at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/sktokens/-/blob/main/README.md

I've tried to install this extension on my dev system, but nothing happened.

So in your searchkit under the Add dropdown where you add displays etc there should now be an option for token.

I'm stuck as @PálRudan. I installed this plugin and another one that makes columns (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/searchkitcolumn) and I see no changes in the Add dropdown menu
